# showing The Error "ConnectionString property has not been initialized" periodically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, connection

I have a website in vb.net and sql server with a high number of users. the problem is that sometimes during the day, the website throws an exception and does not show some parts of a webpage. The authentication is performed using session and cookies. the session Id s are written in a database table and after signing out they are deleted. I do not know what happens but when I restart IIS the problem is obviated but after a time it appears again. the stack trace of my log file is as below. what is the problem?

```
UserID:rezagmc3       
SessionID:uup5l0koj3eacxl3pcqdxmbz
Form Data: No Form Data Found1: Error Description:The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
1: Source:System.Data
1: Stack Trace:   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
1:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
1:    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
1:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
1:    at SoratHesab.SqlHelperParameterCache.DiscoverSpParameterSet(SqlConnection connection, String spName, Boolean includeReturnValueParameter, Object[] parameterValues)
1:    at SoratHesab.SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSetInternal(SqlConnection connection, String spName, Boolean includeReturnValueParameter)
1:    at SoratHesab.SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(SqlConnection connection, String spName, Boolean includeReturnValueParameter)
1:    at SoratHesab.SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(SqlConnection connection, String spName)
1:    at SoratHesab.mySqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(String SectionName, String spName)
1:    at SoratHesab.clsCAccOp.GetLastUpdatedDate(String SectionName)
1:    at SoratHesab.CAcc.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
1: Target Site:Void PermissionDemand()
```

Comment: The error message shows that there is something wrong with your ConnectionString. How did you get your ConnectionString? Is it via Configuration file (Web.Config)? Could you show your SqlConnection code?

Comment: No all of the connection strings are saved in an INI file. and the program reads the values form this file. The problem is that sometime it works fine. and therefore I think the problem is not only the connection string.

Comment: Are u closing connection after Db request is done? Perhaps connection pool is empty